# How to validate input to only accept inputs of exactly 12 digits?

Tags: java

I need to make a upc code validator for class using java. 
The upc validation parts works perfectly but i need a way to only accept a 12 digits input.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
my code looks like this:

```
public class UPC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // get input number
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a 12-digit barcode: "); //prompt user for input
        long input = Keyboard.nextLong();
        long number = input;

        int d11 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d10 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d9 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d8 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d7 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d6 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d5 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d4 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d3 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d2 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d1 = (int) (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        int d0 = (int) (number % 10);

        int m = d1 + d3 + d5 + d7 + d9;
        int n = d0 + d2 + d4 + d6 + d8 + d10;

        int r = (10 - ((m + 3*n) % 10)) % 10;
        System.out.println("Anatomy of Your UPC Barcode");
        System.out.println("====================================");
        System.out.println("                   UPC: " + input);
        System.out.println("                   NSC: " + d0);
        System.out.println("   Manufacturer Number: " + d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5);
        System.out.println("          Product Code: " + d6 + d7 + d8 + d9 + d10);
        System.out.println("           Family Code: " + d6 + d7 + d8);
        System.out.println("            Value Code: " + d9 + d10);
        System.out.println("   Scanned Check Digit: " + d10);
        System.out.println("Calculated Check Digit: " + d11);

        if (r == d11) {
            // is a upc code
            System.out.println("   Validity status: valid");
        }
        else {
            // not a upc code
            System.out.println("   Validity status: invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (str.matches("\\d{12}"))`

Comment: Edited my post, not sure where to put the statement you just gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isOk;
do {

    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a 12-digit barcode: "); //prompt user for input
    try{
        long input = Keyboard.nextLong();
        isOk = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        //non-numeric input detected! 
        isOk = false;
        Sy...print("Only Numbers allowed! Try again.")
    }

    if(isOk){
        if(number<100000000000L || number >999999999999L){
           //number is not 12 digits
           isOk = false;
           Sy...print("Must be 12 digits!! Try again.")
        }else{ 
           //number is 12 digits.
           isOk = true;
        }
    }
}while(!isOk);

//do the rest of your codes here...
```

you can try checking if the number is within the 12 digit range.

Comment: This works perfectly, But can you suggest anything to add to make it validate whether or not the input is also only made of numbers? As the conditions in order to run the program is to have an input that is made of 12 digits and is numerical.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use regular expression like `\\d{12}` to check for digits.

Note that you do not need to append the `^` prefix and `$` suffix, which normally just mean at the start of string and `$` means end of string as the `matches()` api will automatically do that for you.

**Sample code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String barcode = scan.next();

    if (barcode.matches("\\d{12}")) {
        System.out.println("Value " + barcode + " is a valid bar code!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid bar code.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456789000
Value 123456789000 is a valid bar code!

1234567890A
Invalid bar code.
```

**References:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: It does work, but how should I implement it into my code? The rest of the code need to run if the input is valid.

Comment: Just stick the code that you wanted to run eg. `int m = d1 + d3 + d5 + d7 + d9;` into the `.matches(...)` block. That is inside the block where the code prints 'X is a valid bar code'